# Constructing std::function target in-place

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

What I understand as a typical use of `std::function`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class C {
public: 
    C() { cout << "CREATING" << endl; }
    C(const C&) { cout << "COPY C "<< endl; };
    C(C&&) { cout << "MOVE C " << endl; };
    ~C() { cout << "DELETING"<< endl; }
    C& operator =(const C&) {
        cout << "COPY A " << endl; return *this;
    };
    C& operator =(C&&) {
        cout << "MOVE A" << endl; return *this;
    };
    void operator ()() const { cout << "CALLING" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    function<void()> f = C();
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

yields following output

```
CREATING
MOVE C
DELETING
CALLING
DELETING
```

Apparently, temporary object is created on stack and then moved into function object. If move constructor is not provided, it is copied instead.
Is there a standard way of setting the target without need for a temporary object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that `function` is constructed from any functor `F f` is stipulated by the standard in §20.9.11.2.1 as (assuming `f` is a non-null, emphasis mine):

> `*this` targets a **copy** of `f` initialized with **`std::move(f)`**

So there is no way to in-place construct a `function`. That leaves you with a choice between incurring that move:

```
function<void()> f1 = C{};
```

Or passing in some wrapper around `C` that is cheaper to move/copy, either one in which you manage externally:

```
C manage_me;
function<void()> f2 = std::ref(manage_me);
```

... or an allocated one bound to `operator()`:

```
function<void()> f3 = std::bind(&C::operator(), std::make_shared<C>());
```

That last one could cause some headaches if `operator()` happens to be overloaded, as you'd have to cast it to the right type, which is an issue that none of the previous versions have to deal with.

```
function<void()> f4 = std::bind(
                          static_cast<void(C::*)()>(&C::operator()),
                          std::make_shared<C>()
                          );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::bind` but you do not really need to implement `operator()` for that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    C c;
    function<void()> f = std::bind( &C::operator(), &c );
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
CREATING
CALLING
DELETING
```

of course you need to properly maintain lifetime of object c in this case.
To make `std::function` to own `C` instance and make it more in-place construction `std::shared_ptr` can be used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    function<void()> f = std::bind( &C::operator(), std::make_shared<C>() );
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If he's doing `C()`, then the scope of the object will be limited anyway.

Comment: Of course, this isn't utilizing in-place construction but rather no construction at all.  But still worth mentioning and probably useful sometimes somehow.

Comment: Well, no construction inside the function object. ;-)

Comment: If I have to maintain the lifetime of the object anyway, why not then use `function<void()> f = std::ref(C)`?

Comment: @5gon12eder good point, added example for in-place construction.

Comment: That last version is very interesting.  (Honestly, I'm a little surprised that it works.)  If we are worried about the cost of copying the functor, it is probably large so `std::function` would have allocated memory anyway, so, assuming the shared pointer is small enough to make `std::function` utilize its small object optimization, we can create the functor on the free store anyway at no additional cost.

Comment: @Cynic added example where you do not need to maintain lifetime of the object